# How to make Ops method compatible between two objects of a non base class

Tags: r, oop, generics

Let's imagine that I have a class "my" and I want to trigger certain behaviour when it is added to an object that has units (i.e. from `units` package):

```
library(units)
my1 = structure(2, class="my")

Ops.my <- function(e1, e2=NULL) {
  ok <-
    switch(
      .Generic,
      `-` = ,
      `*` = ,
      `+` = ,
      '<=' = TRUE,
      FALSE
    )
  if (!ok) {
    stop(gettextf("%s not meaningful", sQuote(.Generic)))
  }
  get(.Generic)(as.integer(e1), as.integer(e2))
}

my1+set_units(5,nm)
```

Currently, it gives me the following warning:

```
Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.my", "Ops.units") for "+"
```

But I actually want to handle "my" and "units" addition in a certain way, how do I do it?
I tried with something like `Ops.my.units <-`  but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with `Ops`. From the docs:

> The classes of both arguments are considered in dispatching any member of this group. For each argument its vector of classes is examined to see if there is a matching specific (preferred) or Ops method. If a method is found for just one argument or the same method is found for both, it is used. If different methods are found, there is a warning about ‘incompatible methods’

This is probably a good thing. Part of the benefit of an object-oriented system in a non-compiled language like R is that it helps preserve type safety. This stops you from accidentally adding apples to oranges, as we can see in the following example:

```r
apples  <- structure(2, class = "apples")

oranges <- structure(2, class = "oranges")

Ops.apples <- function(e1, e2) {
  value <- do.call(.Generic, list(as.integer(e1), as.integer(e2)))
  class(value) <- "apples"
  value
}

Ops.oranges <- function(e1, e2) {
  value <- do.call(.Generic, list(as.integer(e1), as.integer(e2)))
  class(value) <- "oranges"
  value
}

apples + apples
#> [1] 4
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "apples"

oranges + oranges
#> [1] 4
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "oranges"

apples + oranges
#> [1] 4
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "apples"
#> Warning message:
#>   Incompatible methods ("Ops.apples", "Ops.oranges") for "+"
```

You can see that even here, we *could* just ignore the warning.

```r
suppressWarnings(apples + oranges)
#> [1] 4
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "apples"
```

But hopefully you can see why this may not be good - we have added 2 apples and 2 oranges, and have returned 4 apples.

Throughout R and its extension packages, there are numerous type-conversion functions such as `as.integer`, `as.numeric`, `as.logical`, `as.character`, `as.difftime` etc. These allow for some element of control when converting between types and performing operations on different types.

The "right" way to do this kind of thing is specifically convert one of the object types to the other in order to perform the operation:

```r
as.my <- function(x) UseMethod("as.my")

as.my.default <- function(x) {
  value <- as.integer(x)
  class(value) <- 'my'
  value
}

my1 + as.my(set_units(5,nm))
#> [1] 7
```

Comment: True when you operate on apples and orange, but I want to create a custom numeric data structure ("my") that can have units or not, hence transforming 5 to "my" sounds a bit like an overhead.

Comment: @doXa77o yes, but the problem is that you want to add your custom data type to an existing S3 class over which you have no control. It is possible to do what you are asking by defining a new units class - that way you can write your own methods for it, but you need to be able to write the `Ops` methods for both classes if you want to be able to add them together.

Comment: yup, yup! as you said, with `Ops` and S3 this is impossible. Thanks man! I'm trying the other way, adding to `my` a `unit` class...